# How can I use x->Root outputs from Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, polynomials

Do not understand the meaning of the output given by *Mathematica* to this equation:

```
Solve[x^3-6x^2+x-32==0,x]//FullSimplify
(* {{x->Root[-32+#1-6#1^2+#1^3 &,1]},{x->Root[-32+#1-6#1^2+#1^3 &,3]},{x->Root[-32+#1-6#1^2+#1^3 &,2]}} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Try to apply N@Solve[...] before applying FullSimplify. In this case, the result is already simplified. One real solution and 2 complex solutions. You don't need to apply FullSimplify

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful -- Probably not as important in this question, though.

Comment: Please have a look at the docs for `Root[]` and the duplicate question I linked to. In your case, since you have a cubic equation, remove the `FullSimplify[]` and probably add the option `Cubics -> True` to `Solve[]`.

Comment: `Solve[x^3 - 6 x^2 + x - 32 == 0, x] // Simplify` will give a simpler form in terms of radicals.